# How to change the password field type in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the type of password field (change from password to text).The issue is that clicked Item  (original example there is `eye` pic but the current demo I place a text `see`) is present in `after` of the element.

Could I bind the after element? I am sure 100% we can't  bind `after` element. So how will I toggle my password?

Here is my code
https://jsbin.com/zeterucite/2/edit?html,css,js,output

```
$(function(){
  function signUpAgreeCheckedEventHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    $('#signupConfirmPassword_js').attr('type','text')
        alert('--')
    }
  $('#signupConfirmPassword_js:after').click(signUpAgreeCheckedEventHandler)
})
```

Comment: What do you mean of *could I bind the after element?*

Comment: It mean could I bind pseudo class  element .I think no

Comment: No you can't select pseudo elements by jQuery, just with a class. The problem is pseudo elements or just change password to text?

Comment: I want to click `pseudo` element to see password

Comment: i want to change password type to text type on click of `see` text

Comment: I got you, But as I said you can't select any pseudo elements by jQuery. Because it's out of DOM.

Comment: ok..so we can't do this on `see` text

Comment: Do you want clear text password to be editable or just read only?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, it is not possible to get the `:after` pseudo element by java script. but there are some workarounds for it like as applying `pointer-events: none;` on your main element and a `pointer-events: all;` on its pseudo element as you use in your demo code.

Another option is to add the click event handler for whole main element which includes the `:after` pseudo object and then use some x-y calculations to determine if the click is over the main part or your pseudo element.

```
$('#myPassword').click( function(evt) {
  if (evt.clientX > $(this).offset().left + 100 { //assume input element width is 100px
    // ...
  }
});
```

You may use `e.clientX, e.clientY, e.pageX/Y, $(this).offset().top/left, $(this).outerWidth/outerHeight ...`